# Limit Element Search to driver RFT

Tags: ui-automation, rft

is there a way to limit the searching to a single process or driver in rational functional tester? If i have two instances up at the same time, it doesn't know which one to look at and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using descriptive programming, you could lmit your serach based on the process ID. Have you tried that ?

Comment: nah, i hate RFT went to selenium. much easier